# How to pass numeric input values of components inside flatlist from modal screen to main component screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have a list of items inside a flatlist with numeric inputs of each one of them as follows

[image]

My code for the flatlist is as follows:

```
const BedRoomModal = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text style={Styles.headerText}>Bedroom 1</Text>
          <View style={Styles.container}>
            <FlatList
              data={bedData.BED}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.BED_ID}
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => BedRoomSave()}
          style={{
            alignSelf: 'flex-end',
            right: 5,
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 10,
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#20B2AA',
              alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              padding: 10,
            }}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#fff'}}>
              SAVE
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

renderItem is as follows:

```
 const renderItem = ({item,index}) => {
        return (
          <>
            <View
              style={{
                marginBottom: 24,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
              }}>
              <Text style={Styles.checklistTitle}>{item.BED_TITLE}</Text>
              <NumericInput
        value={bed[index]}
        onChange={(value) => bedDataFunction(value,index)}
        totalWidth={100}
            totalHeight={35}
            iconSize={22}
            step={1}
            valueType="integer"
            textColor="#B0228C"
            iconStyle={{color: 'black'}}
            rightButtonBackgroundColor="#fff"
            leftButtonBackgroundColor="#fff"
        minValue={0}
      
      />
            
            </View>
            <View style={Styles.itemSeparator}></View>
          </>
        );
      };
```

bedDataFunction:

```
const bedDataFunction=(value,id)=>{
    console.log('VALUE')
    console.log(value)
    console.log('ID')
    console.log(id)
 }
```

The states that I have used are:

```
const [bed, setBed] = useState([]);
```

I get the value inside the console of my onchange function but now I need to take that value and display it on screen? could anyone tell what am I doing wrong here?

Any suggestion would be welcomed, am stuck since long now, hopefully would recieve help, thank you.
Let me know if anything is required for better understanding of the code.

Comment: Could you provide ```setBed``` method and I can't understand where come from ```bed``` inside ```renderItem```?

Comment: I have used them as states, have added that you can check

Comment: The issue with this you don't have any flag to know which variable that it is. It means so whenever you update anything all value has been updated. Try adding flag

Comment: could you give some example as to what flag should I use?

Comment: Can you add it into [snack](https://snack.expo.io)

Comment: Yes what @OliverD mentioned is the best. If you could add this on snack

Comment: I would not be able to do that the data is fetched from API,please help here itself